# Performance of join vs pre-select on MsSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I can do the same query in two ways as following, will #1 be more efficient as we don't have join?

## 1

```
select table1.* from table1 
inner join table2 on table1.key = table2.key 
where table2.id = 1
```

## 2

```
select * from table1 
where key = (select key from table2 where id=1)
```

Comment: Run them both with client statistics and actual execution plan turned on in SSMS and find out!

Comment: [Performance rant...](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @GarethD well, most people call this curiosity rather than Performance Rant

Comment: I would also call it curiosity, but the rant is, **you** are in the best position to answer this question and satisfy that curiosity!. Run the two queries to test which is faster - check the execution plan, check the IO statistics - this will give you a far better answer than anyone on Stackoverflow can guess at. The actual answer to your question will depend on your table structures and contraints. As Gordon as pointed out unless `id` is unique in `table2` then your queries are not equivalent. Similarly if `key` is nullable in table2 then your queries are not equivalent.

Comment: @GarethD you were making assumption that everyone know there is a tool to check the execution plan, but this is not the case. And also you are not trying to make the same point as your first comment now, you were just expressing "you should not care about performance too much, dont be the performance rant". I appreciate people try very hard to help people in stack overflow but sometime we do see "hate expression" that make nothing but negative feeling (to everyone)

Comment: Apologies if you have misconstrued my first comment - I was not suggesting that you were the performance rant - The title of the article I was linking to is "Performance Rant" where the author addresses the pitfalls of questions such as this that ask "Which is faster MethodA or MethodB" but do not provide adequate information to answer this question. Not trying to be negative just I had nothing to add to the article so did not add anything, just used the title as the text to click and assumed that you might click through and read it - apologies if this was not the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are doing two different things.  The second will return an error if more than one row is returned by the subquery.

In practice, my guess is that you have an index on `table2(id)` or `table2(id, key)`, and that `id` is unique in `table2`.  In that case, both should be doing index lookups and the performance should be very comparable.

And, the general answer to performance question is:  try them on your servers with your data.  That is really the only way to know if the performance difference makes a difference in your environment.

Comment: so there is no magic happening in mssql to 'optimize' the execution plan from 1 to other depend on which is better?

Comment: Look at the execution plan and you will have your answer.  If the key column is guaranteed to be unique in both tables via a unique constraint or index, I would expect identical plans.  But the optimizer won't know that if there are no such constraints/indexes and the plans will differ.

Answer (score 0):

I executed these two statements after running set statistics io on (on SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise - which supposedly has the best optimization compared to Standard).

select top 5 * from x2 inner join ##prices on
x1.LIST_PRICE = ##prices.i1

and

select top 5 * from x2 where LIST_PRICE in (select i1 from ##prices)

and the statistics matched exactly. I have always preferred the first type of join but the second allows me to select just that part and see what rows are being returned.

I was taught that joins vs subqueries are mostly equivalent when it comes to performance. I would also look at the resulting query plans to see if one is better then the other. The query plans matched exactly.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server is smart enough to understand that it is the same action in such a simple query.
However if you have more than 1 record in subquery then you'll probably use IN. In is slow operation and it will never work faster than JOIN. It can be the same but never faster. 
The best option for your case is to use EXISTS. It will be always faster or the same as JOIN or IN operation. Example:

```
select * from table1 t1
where EXISTS  (select * from table2 t2 where id=1 AND t1.key = t2.key)
```